# Refactoring. Trying to make code more elegant. Need design pattern

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Without going into detail. I have structure like this:

```
class someClass():
    def __init__(self, m):
        
        if m == 1:
            self.mode1()
        elif m == 2:
            self.mode2()
        elif m == 3:
            self.mode3()
        .....

        elif m == 10:
            self.mode10()
```

It's a class with different operating modes. Passing variable `m` to the class I want to set mode of operation running corresponding method of class. Is there way to do this more elegant and get rid of the 'if' statements? May be there is some design pattern for this specific case?

Comment: pass in the behavior.

Comment: What you are describing is called a "switch case" structure in C and C++. Unfortunately python decided not to use this standard. As a replacement for the structure, many people use dictionary mapping as shown here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-case-in-python-replacement/

Comment: Try strategy pattern.

Comment: This is saying you have a variable parent class, which I cant comprehend. Are you certain that is what you're trying to do? Is `m` supposed to be a parameter of the __init__ method?

Comment: Yes, `m` is a parameter of the init method.

Comment: @Robin I have read about the strategy pattern and it is very similar to what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I used strategy pattern. Thanks @Robin for advice.

```
class Strategy(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        pass   

class Context():
    def __init__(self, strategy: Strategy):
        self._strategy = strategy

    @property
    def strategy(self):
        return self._strategy

    @strategy.setter
    def strategy(self,  strategy: Strategy):
        self._strategy = strategy

    def executeStrategy(self):
        self._strategy.execute()

class mode0(Strategy):
    def execute(self):
        logging.info("MODE 0")
        
class mode1(Strategy):
    def execute(self):
        logging.info("MODE 1")
        
class mode2(Strategy):
    def execute(self):
        logging.info("MODE 2")
        
.....
```

then

```
class someClass():
    def __init__(self, m):
        modesList = [mode0, mode1, mode2, mode3, mode4, mode5, 
                     mode6, mode7, mode8, mode9, mode10, mode11]      
    
        ctx = Context(modesList[m]())
        ctx.executeStrategy()
```